# Getting ModuleNotFoundError in DreamBooth running on Google Colab

Tags: python, deep-learning, google-colaboratory, stable-diffusion

I am using [this](https://github.com/TheLastBen/fast-stable-diffusion/blob/main/fast-DreamBooth.ipynb) google colab notebook to run dreambooth using automatic1111 webgui. Everything ran smoothly few days back. But for last few days, I am getting this error. I trained the model, then when I tried to test it to run the automatic1111 webgui, I got this error. I tried replacing these files like `sampling.py` etc. but I am unable to solve this error. Why this error arise? I dont have a fancy gpu (i have nvidia 940 MX 2 Gb) so i use google colab to generate art using dreambooth trained on my own images. Please help me out.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/sd/stable-diffusion-webui/webui.py", line 13,
> in      from modules import shared, devices, sd_samplers,
> upscaler, extensions, localization, ui_tempdir   File
> "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/sd/stable-diffusion-webui/modules/sd_samplers.py",
> line 8, in      import k_diffusion.sampling   File
> "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/sd/stable-diffusion/src/k-diffusion/k_diffusion/**init**.py",
> line 1, in      from . import augmentation, config,
> evaluation, external, gns, layers, models, sampling, utils   File
> "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/sd/stable-diffusion/src/k-diffusion/k_diffusion/external.py",
> line 6, in      from . import sampling, utils   File
> "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/sd/stable-diffusion/src/k-diffusion/k_diffusion/sampling.py",
> line 7, in      import torchsde ModuleNotFoundError: No module
> named 'torchsde'

I deleted all the files, trained a new model. Now I am getting this error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/sd/stable-diffusion-webui/webui.py", line 13,
> in 
> from modules import shared, devices, sd_samplers, upscaler, extensions, localization, ui_tempdir   File
> "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/sd/stable-diffusion-webui/modules/sd_samplers.py",
> line 11, in 
> from modules import prompt_parser, devices, processing, images   File
> "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/sd/stable-diffusion-webui/modules/processing.py",
> line 15, in 
> import modules.sd_hijack   File "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/sd/stable-diffusion-webui/modules/sd_hijack.py",
> line 10, in 
> import modules.textual_inversion.textual_inversion   File "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/sd/stable-diffusion-webui/modules/textual_inversion/textual_inversion.py",
> line 13, in 
> from modules import shared, devices, sd_hijack, processing, sd_models, images, sd_samplers   File
> "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/sd/stable-diffusion-webui/modules/sd_models.py",
> line 8, in 
> import safetensors.torch ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'safetensors'